# How to keep checked state of checkbox after submit or page refresh in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I want to keep checked state of checkbox after page refresh or submit. In my code checkbox is inside dropdown button after submit results are shown but doesn't keep checked state.

Here is my html code.

HTML:

```
    <form method="GET" name="frm1" action="filter.php" id="form">
    <div class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
        <button type="button"  class="btn mr-2 mt-1 fillbtn" style="background-color:#494f4d; color: white; float:right; font-size:11px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;MOVIES
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right ml-4" style="background-color:black; width:100%; height:90%;">

        <div class="row rounded rowtv" style="background-color:black; color:#d2d8d6;">
            <h4 class="mb-3 mt-3 border-bottom" style=" margin:auto; color:#76ff03; font-family:bold;">Movies</h4>
        </div>


        <div class="row rounded rowtv" style="background-color:black; color:#d2d8d6;">


        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 tvgen">

        <h4>Genre</h4>

        <div  class="" style="display:inline-block; margin-left:15px;" >
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids"  name="search[]" value="action">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description" >Action</span>
        </label><br>

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids"  name="search[]" value="adventure">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Adventure</span>
        </label><br> 

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids" name="search[]" value="animation">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Animation</span>
        </label><br> 

        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input ids" name="search[]" value="biography">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Biography</span>
        </label><br>

        </div> 

        </div> 

    </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below uses javascript and cookies to keep the state of checkboxes on submit or page refresh.

Javascript:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="search[]"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
      if (getCookie('search[' + chks[i].value + ']') == 'true') {
        chks[i].checked = true;
      }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
      chks[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.cookie = "search[" + this.value + "]=" + this.checked + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2018 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
      });

    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
      var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
          c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
          return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
      }
      return "";
    }
  });
</script>
```